# Are questions about external render engines on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions specifically about external render engines (engines not bundled with official blender) allowed?

For example, [What's going wrong with my Luxrender Prism?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27805/whats-going-wrong-with-my-luxrender-prism)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't see any reason not to allow these, but I suggest that it be limited to render engines with blender integration (i.e. usable directly from blender's UI).

Using external render engines seems like a fairly common thing among blender users, and I think it definitely fits under our current scope:

> The Blender Stack Exchange site is for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games.

Comment: I agree with this.

Comment: Could be interesting for all, but a new tag like `luxrender` would be nice.

Comment: I'm fine with questions about partially integrated tools.

Comment: @poor I was thinking about that.. I've posted another meta: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/674/should-we-have-tags-for-external-render-engines-which-have-blender-integration?lq=1

Comment: You should mention that this is all right so long as it refers to using the renderer _with Blender._

Comment: @AWildRolandiXor `render engines with blender integration` means `using the renderer with blender ` - For sure we could distinguish, if the render process happens directly in blender or needs a separate application, but I think this doesn't matter to specify this, as long blender is the main application, which is sending the job to the renderer.

Comment: @poor sorry about that - I missed that part when I read it the first time. :P