# Should we have tags for external render engines which have blender integration?

Tags: discussion, tags

As a follow up to [Are questions about external render engines on topic?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/672/are-questions-about-external-render-engines-on-topic), should we have specific tags for popular external render engines (e.g. [luxrender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luxrender) [yafaray](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yafaray) etc.)

Or a single generic tag like [external-render-engines](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-render-engines), albeit separate from the uber-general [external-applications](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-applications) tag?

How specific or general should our tags be?

Comment: Possible dupe http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/286/how-should-we-deal-with-tags-about-other-software/

Comment: @iKlsR Hm.. I'm asking more specifically about external render engines *which are integrated into blender*

Answer (score 7):

I'm always in favor of more specific tags. So if the question base is there to warrant a new tag, then by all means add it. I do wonder if it is realy needed at this point (I'm the one, nearly a year ago now, that removed the yafaray tag), Luxrender only has 8 questions, Yafaray has 4, etc.
There are other question groups, with many more questions that are denied the right to get their own tag. <sub>*Yes iklsr, I'm talking about **knife tool***</sub>

However, I do not think that we should just go and add a new tag for each conceivable render engine, because we have decided to add a "Luxrender" tag.  If nobody asks about Povray, then it does not need a tag.

Let the question demand drive what new tags we have, rather then because we *decided* to create this tag.

Comment: +1 For the last sentence in particular

Comment: Knife tool, spin tool, smooth tool, add all the tools!